# web3js Uniswap handle event log data

Tags: ethereum, web3js, uniswap

I am building a scraper to get all Swap data from Uniswap using web3js.
So far I subscribe to the log and filter topics by Swap() event.
then I decode the data and get amount0In, amount1In, amount0Out, amount1Out.

My problem is in the swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens() function.
Normally a swap has token0 in and token1 out, but this function gives me values for 3 of the 4 and I can not seem to understand how to handle that. eventually what I want is to know what they spend, what they got and what I need to update the new reserves of that pair.

If someone has the understanding of the Uniswap RouterV2 contract swap functions, I would like to get some pointers on how to handle the data to get my calculations right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here [ethereum.stackexchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99553/how-to-understand-the-swap-event-payload) Anyone with the same question gets a very detailed answer there.

some contracts actually transfers to recipient specified amount of tokens minus 10% (5% tax fee and 5% liquidity fee) 208940457743532637 - 10% = 188046411969179375 and emits Transfer event. Then, PancakePair _swap function emits Swap event with base value of Amount0Out 208940457743532637

Amount0In is greater than zero because the token contract returns part of  tokens as a liquidity pair on Pancake Swap.